# Выбор языка web-программирования

Tags: любой-язык

Сразу хочу извиниться. Знаю, что такие вопросы уже задавали тут, но я его поставлю немного по-другому.

Если бы у вас было каких-то 10 абстрактных skill-point-ов, в какие языки/технологии вы бы их раскидали?
Предполагаемые варианты:

- PHP
- .Net
- node.js
- Ruby-on-Rails
- свой вариант

**P. S.** Сам работаю на .net, коммерческого опыта год. Думаю, пока не поздно попробовать себя в других местах.

**P. P. S** За скилл-поинты можно посчитать время, потраченное на изучении и работу.

Comment: > коммерческого опыта год  

За год человек вполне способен самостоятельно осознать, куда ему податься. Не?

Comment: @teanЫЧ я за пол года определился что мне нравится ))) но все равно больше подстраиваюсь под работодателя, который мне нравится :)

Comment: >>За год человек вполне способен самостоятельно осознать, куда ему податься. Не?
Решать конечно же мне. Но нужен взгляд со стороны. Не зря же вопрос задал.

Comment: @IVsevolod, у меня тоже самое :) За месяц работы с 1С я понял, что мне это не надо, но зарплата... В общем учу с++ и жду, когда апну 90 lvl. Вот тогда буду все кардинально менять.

Comment: за год вполне можно было изучить равномерно эти технологии, хотя бы изучить основы ) а дальше тупо смотреть спрос ) Для лингвистов-программистов новые языки легко даются, и в короткие сроки.

Comment: я хоть и PHP-шник, советую изучить Perl...

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай я тоже PHP-шник, и советую оба языка изучить :)

Answer (score 2):

В прямой зависимости от прогноза зарплат на ближайшие лет 5-10.
Это в случае, если бы скиллпоинты позволяют мгновенно получить скилл.
Если надо долго учить, что гораздо ближе к реальности, то выбрал бы то, что выбрал сейчас

- PHP
- JS

На остальное - максимум по одному очку. Чтобы только понимать о чем речь.

Comment: > скиллпоинты позволяют мгновенно получить скилл  

причем приличный скилл. Ибо на рынке полно студентоты, готовой работать за роллтон, и с ними надо конкурировать. У меня есть знакомый, который заканчивает вуз в следующем году. У него вся группа спит и видит, как они будут тру-программистами PHP и будут зарабатывать сотни тысяч валюты. И это частный случай. Таких  товарищей каждый ИТ вуз ежегодно сотнями выпускает.

Comment: С ними конкурировать бесполезно, если ни одного СП не потрачено на "sale skill". Потому что либо заказчик понимает, что за ролтон он лапшу и получит, либо НЕ понимает. И только хороший продажник сможет убедить клиента, почему он должен отдать исполнение именно ЭТОМУ программеру.

Comment: Большинству заказчиков плевать, что у них там внутри проекта. Главное, чтобы работало, и в бюджет укладывалось.

Comment: @teanЫЧ плевать до первого печального опыта ) Когда их программисты начинают понимать, что зашли в тупик, и никак, совсем никак не допилить до нужного результата, и нужно переписывать ту работу, которые делали 2 года )

Comment: Да, это второй тип. Поэтому я и говорю: нужен sale-skill. Иначе, следуя "здравой логике", человек выберет портал за 100 денег, а не магазин за 1000

Comment: @IVsevolod, если бы до первого, проблем бы не было. В среднем, заказчик бьется в эту стенку примерно до тех пор, пока сумма не превысит однократную работу профессионала. Принцип "скупой платит дважды" таки работает.

Но самое печальное, что некоторые после печального опыта идут и заказывают по принципу цены. То есть, тоже у ролтонов, но уже по цене профи. И это ужасно

Answer (score 2):

Ну, т.к. это веб программирование, то вот так:

- **PHP** = **4**
- **Perl** = **2** (в зависимости от предпочтений, можно c **PHP** поменяться пойнтами)
- **JS** = **2** (Из них **1** на **jQuery**)
- **HTML** = **1**
- **CSS** = **1**